# Mapbox GL Map not centering on initial location

Tags: angular, google-maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm using mapbox gl in Angular 2 to plot a map based on the user's current location. my code goes as follows:

```
executemap() {
console.log(this.locationService.currentLat, this.locationService.currentLng);
this.map = new mapbox.Map({
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
  center: [this.locationService.currentLat, this.locationService.currentLng],
  zoom: 9,


  container: 'map'
});


console.log('map loaded');
console.log(this.map);
    console.log(this.map.getCenter().toString());
var latLng = new mapbox.LngLat(this.locationService.currentLat,this.locationService.currentLng);
this.map.resize();
this.map.setZoom(2);
```

}

in this example, I'm using the coordinates 41.8692324 -87.6630301, which is chicago (based on my console logs I can verify that the coordinates are there when initializing the map). I'm getting these coordinates from google places. When I run the map, for some reason it centers on antarctica:

[image]

I'm using the default styles and tileset for this. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

You have the Lat / Lng  the wrong way around!

Also its recommended you consider if the user denies access to the geolocation information (IP). I would recommend adding in a default lat/lng to fall back on and perhaps a messsage - It defaults to New York in this example.

```js
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  crd = pos.coords;
  loadMap(crd.longitude,crd.latitude);
};

function error(err) {
  console.log(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
  loadMap(-73.935242,40.730610);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

function loadMap(lng,lat) {
 mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGF2aWRiYXR0eSIsImEiOiJjajBqc2hqZ3YwMDN5MndvbDUxaDhoMDV6In0.w7sfrB5JeCH92sY-l0TQSg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', // stylesheet location
    center: [lng,lat], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
}
```

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
```

```html
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```